# Implemetation not found and get a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot 2 application with spring data jpa and hibernate with postgres

```
package com.acmor.togy.repository.util.postgres
@Component
public class HStoreParameter implements FormatParameter{
    ...
}

package com.acmor.togy.repository.util;
public interface FormatParameter {
    String format(Map<String, String> properties);
}

package com.acmor.togy.repository.util;
public class AbstractRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> {

    private ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> parameters = new ThreadLocal<>();

    @Autowired
    private FormatParameter formatParameter;

    public AbstractRepository(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }

    public AbstractRepository(Class domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }

}

package com.acmor.togy.repository;
@Repository
public class EnumsRepositoryImpl extends AbstractRepository implements EnumsRepositoryCustom {
}

public interface EnumsRepositoryCustom {
    ...
}
```

I created a basic test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EnumsRepositoryCustomTest {
     @Autowired
    private EnumsRepositoryCustom enumsRepository;

    @Test
    public void test_advanced_search_using_properties() {
        EnumsSearch search = new EnumsSearch();
        ...
        Page<Enums> page = enumsRepository.search(search, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
        ...
    }
}
```

When I run test I get

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.acmor.togy.repository.util.FormatParameter' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I have a implementation of FormatParameter, it's HStoreParameter

Comment: Looks like your test is not configured to scan for beans.You should e.g. add a `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` annotation to your test class (pointing to your application class where the package scan is configured)

Comment: In my main class of my application, I have @SpringBootApplication

Comment: did you try to autowire it as: private HStoreParameter hStoreParameter ?

Comment: Does it start when you run with mvn spring-boot:run or java -jar ... command?

Comment: yes that start without issue

Comment: used springboot test instead of jpa one... and worked

Comment: Could you post the Code for that Component-Implementation of `HStoreParameter`?